# Remove fine line between Containers in a Row

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a row with a steps and separators. Each step is wrapped in an Expand; the separator has a fixed size.

The Expanded causes the containers to have a fine white line between them

[image: white lines between containers]

When i remove the `Expanded`, the lines are gone

[image: white lines gone when Expanded is removed]

Anybody know a fix or workaround?

The code looks similar to this

```dart
Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: height,
        color: AppTheme.blue,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Define",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: AppTheme.white,
              fontSize: 13,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: height,
      width: height/2.0,
      color: AppTheme.blue
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Container(
        height: height,
        color: AppTheme.grey,
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "Mix 1",
            style: TextStyle(
              color: AppTheme.black,
              fontSize: 13,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      height: height,
      width: height/2.0,
      color: AppTheme.grey
    ),
    ...
  ]
)
```

EDIT 1:
The reason why i am doing all this is that the final separator need to be custom pained.

[image: custom paint]

I now do custom paint the steps, so the container is gone.
The code now looks similar to this

```dart
Expanded(
  child: CustomPaint(
    painter: StepPainter(
      isActive: isActive,
      height: height,
      text: TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: isActive ? AppTheme.white : AppTheme.darkGrey,
          fontSize: 13,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: Do you tried to wrap your widgets with Flexible instead of using Expanded?

Comment: just tried it, it’s the same effect

Comment: why not wrap the other Containers with Expanded?

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL because the final result needed to looks different. see my last edit for details.

Answer (score -1):

since you didn't provide the code of StepPainter, what if you just apply white border to the object?